# Release build introduces bugs with COM objects

Tags: com, build, rcw

I have a clas library in which I use [OutlookStorage.cs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32899/Reading-an-Outlook-MSG-File-in-C) to read an (Outlook .msg) email and the attachments within that email. I open each attachment with a custom document viewer which converts whatever the attachment is to a PDF. In debug mode, this works perfectly. When in release mode, after reading 1 attachment, a COM exception is thrown which states "COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used."

The properties which make the release build work are: 1. Optimize code must be disabled. 2. In Advanced Build Settings, the Debug Info setting must be set to Full.

I have tried to disable optimisation on the method by adding an attribute as follows:

```cs
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
```

but this didn't make a difference if the Optimize code option for release mode settings was enabled anyway.

This is the code that reads the stream from the COM objects:

```cs
    foreach (OutlookStorage.Attachment attachment in _attachments)
    {
      using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
      {
        stream.Write(attachment.Data, 0, attachment.Data.Length);
        string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(attachment.Filename).Replace(".", "");
        Pdf document = new Pdf(stream, fileExtension);
        DocumentDetailControl document = new DocumentDetailControl(document);
        OpenInNewDialog(document);
      }
    }
```

_attachments is a generic list and OpenInNewDialog returns after the document has opened (there is no waiting for user intervention).

Is there anyone who can shed some light on this? Is there something I can do in the code to prevent the release build from introducing this bug?

Comment: On what line exactly do you get this exception? Please post the full stack frame.

Comment: Hi. When the foreach tries to get the next item in the list.

Comment: Please post the full stack frame.

Comment: I unfortunately can't do that. I believe the problem lies in the handling of the COM objects in OutlookStorage.cs with .NET 4. I have decided to use a different solution.